# NullReferenceException at SqlConnection conn = new

Tags: c#

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

getting exception at this line

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
                       ConfigurationManager.
                       ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSourceRegistration"].
                       ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Your connection string SqlDataSourceRegistration does not exist

Comment: on web.config its unable to find the key SqlDataSourceRegistration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string `SqlDataSourceRegistration` does not exist.

Check your `app.config` or `web.config` and check whether you spelled the connection string right, or whether you added it at all. Read [MSDN: Connection Strings and Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) how to do this.

EDIT:

The connection string is called `RegistrationConnectionString`.

Use this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
                       ConfigurationManager.
                       ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].
                       ConnectionString);
```

Comment: <configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="RegistrationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Registration.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
 already added